# How to insert into column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have four column named `Name, Date, Items` and `Amount`. I want to insert many Items and that's amount at same name and same date. How to do that?

Comment: Could you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qlyJn.png

Answer (score 2):

You can put more rows into database by this way:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, date, items, amount) VALUES
('name1', '2015-05-10', 'items here', 1),
('name2', '2015-05-10', 'items here', 5),
('name3', '2015-05-10', 'items here', 3),
('name4', '2015-05-10', 'items here', 9),
('name5', '2015-05-10', 'items here', 1)
```

The SQL query should be prepeared with using `for` or `foreach` loop, if you have array of items.